# AWS Cloudwatch/Lambda - scheduled event is triggered too often

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

i created an **AWS Lambda function**, and created a scheduled event **rule** in **Cloudwatch** to trigger it every 5 minutes : 
`Schedule Cron expression : 0/5 * * * ? *`

The problem is that when looking at the logs, the Lambda seems to be executed every 1~2 minute.

I checked the CRON expression, it seem correct because AWS shows previews of the next triggers. I also tried with a rate expression, but i still have the same issue.

I tooks a look at cloudwatch metrics :
- The scheduled event seems fine, it triggered once every 10minutes
- The lambda invocation metric show that it is invoked more often

Any help ?

Comment: Could something else be triggering your lambda?

Comment: @LouO. i only used 1 trigger with SQS. I verified by disabling the Event rule, and the lambda stopped logging, so i guess it's fine on this side

Comment: Could you please edit your question to better explain what you have configured? The title mention SQS, but your question mentions a cron trigger. The correct way to associate Lambda with an Amazon SQS queue is to create a trigger that will invoke the Lambda function whenever a message goes into the SQS queue. A cron expression is not required. Please provide us more information about your setup.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein my bad, have been switching services all day. It's cloudwatch that has a rule that has a scheduled event that should trigger the lambda function every 5 minutes, but instead, it's triggered every 2minutes..

Comment: Are the previous executions of the Lambda function completing successfully (with no errors or timeouts)?

Comment: Can you try the alternate format of `rate(5 minutes)`? See: [Schedule Expressions Using Rate or Cron - AWS Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/tutorial-scheduled-events-schedule-expressions.html)

Comment: Actually i wasn't returning a result. Maybe the problem comes from here @JohnRotenstein

Comment: @JohnRotenstein thanks for the lead, it was the JS promise handler that had to return a result

Answer (score 4):

Thanks @JohnRotenstein for the lead,

the issue came from the returned result from the NodeJS promise.
If the JS **handler** doesn't give back any result inside the returned promise, lambda considers the execution as a failure.

In my case i simply had to return a value (even **null**) so that the execution completes successfully.
Otherwise it looks like lambda will to re-execute the code 1~2 minutes later

Comment: Same thing happened with me. I though ended up increasing the time out in Lambda